# How to compile a flash project from brightcove closed caption module?

Tags: flash

I forgot how to compile flash projects.  Anyway, let me explain my specific scenario.

I'm following the instructions here : http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/using-closed-captions-without-custom-fields to learn how to modify a closed caption plugin for the bright cove video player.

I started by downloading the closed caption module code here: http://files.brightcove.com/ClosedCaptionsModule.zip .

After I downloaded it and unzipped it, I modified the file `src/ClosedCaptionsModule.as`.  Now the instructions tell me to compile this into a SWF file.   How exactly do I do that?  I looked at all the top menu items in Adobe Flash CS4, but I don't see any Build or Compile command.  The Debug movie and Test movie actions are grayed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile a .swf you need to first make a new ActionScirpt 3 project then set the project's class to "ClosedCaptionsModule". Also, for simplicity's sake I would make sure the "ClosedCaptionsModule.as" file is in the same directory as you .fla (project) file, (assuming it is not part of a package).

[image]

Comment: The ClosedCaptionsModule.as file starts with the line `package {`.  I suppose that means it's packaged?  I'm not sure how to "include" the contents of ClosedCaptionsModule into my project...

Comment: I tried opening up the Actions dialog, then copied the contents of ClosedCaptionsModule.as into the Actions dialog.  When i tried to export the swf movie, it says packages can not be nested and fails.

Comment: "package {" means it is using the default package, shouuldn't be a problem. Do not copy the class into the actions panel, as it can be very problematic without the proper code modifications. Did you try setting the project's class to the class file? What happens when you try to compile after doing that?